# WordPress php code not rendering on page when using FireFox

Tags: php, firefox

I am creating a carousel banner, and my code renders perfectly on Google Chrome but breaks on FireFox (but only when I am signed out of WordPress - if I am signed in as admin then FireFox renders it fine). Below is my code:

```
<banner>

   <div class="container-fluid py-5 cool-grey">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-10 mx-auto">
         <div class="flickity-carousel multi-carousel multi-carousel-eq-height" data-flickity='{ "cellAlign": "left", "contain": true, "groupCells": true }'>

   <?php
        $args = array( 'numberposts' => '60' );
        $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
        $noticias_highlight = true;

        foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){ 
?>


                     <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-4 carousel-cell">
            <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-img-mask card-img-mask-top">
                    <img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($recent["ID"])
?>" alt="Card image cap">
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h3 class="card-title"><?php  print_r($recent["post_title"]) ?></h3>
                      <p class="card-text"><?php  print_r($recent["post_excerpt"]) ?></p>
                      <a href="<?php  print_r($recent["guid"]) ?>" class="card-link">View Full Post</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
          </div>

<?php
        } 
?>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
  </banner>
```

When I am signed out of FireFox it renders the code as text:

```
 '60' ); $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args ); $noticias_highlight = true; foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){ ?>
```

and then has a small box of text below that:

```
<img src="" alt="Card image cap">

<a href="" class="card-link">View Full Post
```